# A Bi-Level Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a problem in which I need to maximize a function over a vector of $X:\mathbb{R}^{N}_{++},Y:\mathbb{R}^{N}_{++}$. The maximization problem looks like this,

$$ \max_{X} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} f_{n}(x_{n}) - \min_{Y}  g(Y;X) \right) $$

where for each $n$, $f_{n}(x_{n})$ is continuous, differentiable, increasing and strictly concave and $g$ is a convex, differentiable, continuous function where X is a parameter on the constraint (which define a convex set) of the minimization of $g(\cdot)$. Everything is well behaved. Therefore, the optimal values of $Y$ will be a function of $X$, $Y(X)$. In other words, the inner problem is such that

$$ \min_{Y}  g(Y)  $$
$$ \text{s.t} \hspace{5pt} h(Y,X)\leq 0  $$

Everything is well behaved and therefore **envelope conditions** apply. The only issue is that I cannot compute the minimizer $Y(X)$ in a closed form, I need to use numerical optimization for solving the inner problem. Also, I do not have a closed form for the Lagrange multipliers of the constraints of the inner nest.

---

One potential solution, is to guess a vector of X's, solve for the inner minimization problem and compute the Lagrange multipliers, invoke the Envelope Condition to get a value of the derivative with respect to X in the inner problem and solve for the outermost problem using first order conditions. This process yields a new vector of X, and iterate until convergence.

However, this is **too slow**.

---

Is there any strategy to solve this on one step? Any properties of optimization that one can appeal to?

What is the challenge? If I were able to get the value of the multipliers for any value of X in the inner problem, then solving the problem would be straightforward. I guess that the issue is that to compute those multipliers I need to fix a vector of X and then these are functions of X.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you mean $g$ is convex in $Y$ when $X$ is fixed?